# Any way to use test.load data when running Anonymous Block in Developer Console?

Tags: apex, unit-test

Cannot run our code in Anonymous Block using the test.loaddata statement. When running without the @isTest annotation fails since the "test.loaddata" statement can only be used for test methods.

When adding the @isTest annotation get errors related to top level classes. Below would be an example of code we'd want to run in Dev Console but cannot.

```
    try{
        // Creates bulk Addresses. Initially uses Static Resource data file
        List<Address__C> testbulkaddr = Test.loadData(Address__c.sObjectType, 'testAddresses');
        System.assertEquals(testbulkaddr.size(),200);

        If (testbulkaddr.isEmpty()== False){
        update testbulkaddr;
        } else {
        System.debug('Error list is empty. Size of testbulkaddr is '+ testbulkaddr.size());
            return null;
        }
    } catch (ListException e){
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I"m afraid you're out of luck here, as you correctly state in your question those methods can only be used during tests.

If you're in a developer environment you could load with dataloader or similar, or just write a method that can generate a list of 200 address objects and insert them (with an option to remove them after), e.g.:

```
List<Address__c> addresses = new List<Address__c>();

for(Integer i = 0; i < 300; i++)
{
    addresses.add(new Address__c(Street__c = i + ' Test Street';
}

insert addresses;
```